# Meaning of “tour de chauffe”?

Tags: sens, expressions

From Le Monde, referring to the Republican debate:

> Aux Etats-Unis, tour de chauffe pour les candidats républicains.

Qu'est-ce que c'est qu'un tour de chauffe?

Answer (score 7):

Un tour de chauffe est un "**warm-up lap**". Donc on pourrait dire un tour de piste pour s'échauffer.

J'imagine que dans le contexte les candidats ont surement fait un premier événement pour leur campagne.